# Should I trim back sun-damaged parts of my bamboo?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, pruning, sunlight, bamboo

I recently moved house and brought a bamboo plant with me in a pot. The plant spent a couple of hours in a car on the hottest day of the year and the top 1ft got burnt by the Sun.

It's doing great in the new garden and has grown several new shoots and leaves near the bottom, but the top still looks very brown.

[image: Photo of bamboo now]

Should I chop off this burnt section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can cut it off - take it out as close to the base, or any new growth, as possible. A few canes regularly die back and new ones grow all the time on mature bamboo anyway - that's how we get bamboo canes to use as supports for other plants!